# IS there any way I can add custom colums to ContactsContract database in android

Tags: android

I wanted to know if it is possible to add a custom column to the existing ContactsContract database in android?

Comment: I wanted to know if it is possible beacuse according to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/KIr9OickOK4 this thread it requires root access. If it is possible I would like some pointers on how to do it? Do i simply extend the SqliteOpenHElper and send in an alter query to ContactsContract. If not what are the other option available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, that database is maintained by an app other than yours. The only way for you to change the database is to build your own copy of the Android OS, with a modified version of that `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually:

1. ContactsContract is a class that contains constants. These constants describe various tables and columns in the Contacts Provider.
2. You can add custom rows to the table defined by ContactsContract.Data, subject to the caveats described in the documentation.

Comment: Do you think it is better to use my own database and use numbers as the primary key or create a new constant in the contract contact database

Comment: create your own database and add your new columns there, because in any case it's only your application that knows about these columns so there's no point in trying to add them to the original database unless you also want to rebuild the phone application to use these columns. Also, to identify which contact a row is related to, use the contact id and not the phone number, the phone number can be written in many different ways therefore it can't be used as a unique identifier.

Comment: "You can add custom rows to the table defined by ContactsContract.Data, subject to the caveats described in the documentation" -- the OP was inquiring about custom columns. `ContactsContract.Data` has a family of generic columns (`DATA1` through `DATA15`) that can be overloaded based on the `MIMETYPE` of a row. That may meet the OP's requirement, but I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that the OP already knew about those, and that assumption may have been faulty -- my apologies. However, you cannot add physical columns to a third-party database short of recompiling the code.

Comment: Is it safe to make the assumption that Data.Data10 is not used by any other application for storing it own data. If not how would I check it?